# How to convert List of int array to 2D Array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, data-structures, java-8

Given a list of `int[] [{7, 0}, {7, 1}, {6, 1}, {5, 0}, {5, 2}, {4, 4}]` I need to convert it into 2D Array `{{7, 0}, {7, 1}, {6, 1}, {5, 0}, {5, 2}, {4, 4}}` using Java 8.

Before Java 8 we could use the following logic: `temp` is `List<int[]>` which contains above list of elements. First `res[][]` is created of the same size as a List of elements in `temp`.

```
int[][] res = new int[temp.size()][2];
for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
   res[i][0] = temp.get(i)[0];
   res[i][1] = temp.get(i)[1];
}
```

Comment: This worked with java 8+. I don't think your problem has anything to do with the java version you are using or don't understand what is the problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
List<int[]> list = List.of(
    new int[] {7, 0}, new int[] {7, 1},
    new int[] {6, 1}, new int[] {5, 0},
    new int[] {5, 2}, new int[] {4, 4});
int[][] res = list.stream().toArray(int[][]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(res));
```

result

```
[[7, 0], [7, 1], [6, 1], [5, 0], [5, 2], [4, 4]]
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/NLmOnN).

Comment: Up-voted, but `list.toArray(int[][]::new)` (without the `stream()` call) works quiet as well too, but is Java 11+. For all Java versions, not just Java 8+, `list.toArray(new int[0][])` works great.

Comment: `List.of` is also java 9+, I don't know if using streams is any better in this case and if it solves the OP problem, if there was any.

Comment: Mind that this makes a shallow copy. The example code in the question does a deep copy.